# Avoid page back to top after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 2000);
});
});
```

in order to smooth scroll down when my nav elements are clicked... the problem is that if a link is clicked before page finish loading, when it finishes the page will go back to top again.

I thought event.preventDefault(); was to avoid that. Help please.

Comment: I try with return false instead of event.preventDefault but didn't work... I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the document.onLoad event instead.

document.ready is invoked after all of the HTML is brought down into the document and ready for parsing.

onLoad on the other hand is invoked after all images / resources are loaded into the page as well.

If you wait for this event, then you should have desired results. although they won't have any click functionality until then.

Furthermore, preventDefault does not avoid this. All that does is disable the default action of the element you apply it to. so it prevent's whatever the default action would be for your 'scroll' elements

Comment: I think onload is a very long wait for a navigation to work correctly... since it waits for everything to be loaded. I am right?

Comment: depending on the content, yes it can take a while. im not sure how you can prevent the scrollbar resetting.